# VBScript runtime error '800a01a8', Object required: '' when using WScript.Quit

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am putting the final pieces into a VBScript page and one thing I want to handle is if the variable being passed in via the URL is empty.  If that is the case, I want the page to stop running and show a 'must log in' message.

I have the following code in place:

```
<%
If (Request.QueryString("nn") = "") Then
Response.Write "<p>You must be logged in to view content. <a href='http://URL/login?ReturnUrl=/interests'>Click here</a> to log in.</p>"
    WScript.Quit
End If
%>
```

The error throws on the line `WScript.Quit`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WScript.Quit`, as the name implies, is part of the `Windows Script Host`. You appear to be using VBScript within a different host: ASP. If you need to stop processing an ASP page, just end the server's response by using:

```
Response.End
```

Comment: *facepalm*  I knew it had to be something simple, but couldn't see the forest for the trees.  Thanks @Bond!